# delayed foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a script that is moving .pak files from server1 to server2 with a `foreach` loop. I need the `foreach` loop to wait in-between the file moves to copy over. I'm looking to add a 30 second delay in the loop.

```cs
$server1 = "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp" ## current source folder
$server2 = "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\Target\" ## destination folder

foreach ($server1 in gci $server1 -Include *.pak -Recurse) {
    ## Move the files to the destination folder
    Move-Item -Path $server1.FullName -Destination $server2  
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to wait between?

Comment: To allow the files to files to copy because of a lot of variables like network speed and traffic. I don't want to start hundreds or thousands of file copies at once and crash to servers.

Comment: Do you find the copies are happening synchronously? I can easily be wrong but those copies should be happening one at a time anyway. Regardless you should be using robocopy for something like this as you can put rate limits on it and have it select the files you want.

Comment: Josh  what is robocopy?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc733145(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do, is use the [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-5.1) command:

```
foreach ($server1 in gci $server1 -include *.pak -recurse)
{ 
    ## Move the files to the destination folder
    Move-Item -path $server1.FullName -destination  $server2
    Start-Sleep -s 30
}
```

However, you may find that depending on any number of variables (network speed etc) you are not waiting enough. Then you either need to wait longer or create a function that polls for some condition to be true.

I thought Move-Item would block until the file is copied?

Comment: Thank you Ralph and to answer your questions I am not sure if the move-item waits or not.